# Reversing user input array in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to shift the user number input from right to left.  It seems to be working except for not registering the first number.  I think because for the reverse portion I have count is 1.  I've tried using 0 and vice verse, but it results in an error.  Any ideas on how to shift the user numbers?
The desired output is the reverse of what the user inputs.  Example: User inputs 3 numbers.  3.0 2.0 1.0.  Reverse 1.0. 2.0. 3.0.

```
// import Scanner 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrays {


   public static void main (String [] args){

      int count=0;

      //introduce Scanner
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      //printout question asking for user input and use count as input variable
      System.out.println("Please input the size of array");
      count=input.nextInt();
      //create array and connect count to it
      double[] numbers = new double [count];

      System.out.println("Please input  "+ numbers.length+ " double numbers");
      //create for loop for original number order

      for ( count=0; count<numbers.length; count++){

         numbers[count] = input.nextDouble(); 

         System.out.print( +numbers[count] + "  ");     

      }

      //print out the reverse order
      System.out.print("\n After Reverse Order " );

      //create for loop for reversed number order
      for (count =  1;  count< numbers.length; count++){

         numbers[count-1]=numbers[count];

         System.out.println ( "\n"+ numbers[count] );   

      }



   } 
}
```

Comment: It will help if you provide sample input and desired output.  Then, you can write a test for it and work to make the test succeed.  But please don't do everything in `main`.  And don't call your class `Arrays`, as there is a `java.util.Arrays` class, and readers will be confused.

Comment: my desired sample output is the reverse of what the user inputs.  Example,  User inputs 4 numbers 4., 3., 2., 1.  Reverse 1. 2. 3. 4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the order of elements, that's REVERSE ORDER not SHIFT. "Shift" correctly would shift them all one to the right or left, either dropping the end element or or (possibly) rotating it round to the other end.

So first thing is, to know what you're actually talking about.

Reversing the order of integers in an array:

```
int i = 0;
int j = numbers.length - 1;   // corresponding index at opposite end of array.

// stop when half the array has been swapped.. with the other half.
while (i < j) {               
    // swap between ends.
    int swap = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = swap;

    // advance indices.
    i++;  j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Double[] numbers = new Double[count];
...
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```